# PowerShell: What is the difference between 1234 and (1234)?

Tags: powershell, casting, string-formatting, evaluation

I was hoping that someone could help me out with the following:

```
Function Get-FormattedNameValuePair([string] $name, [object] $value)
{
    return "$("{0,-24}" -f $name) : $("{0,15:N2}" -f $value)"
}

Write-Output (Get-FormattedNameValuePair -name MyField -value 1234)
```

The above returns:

```
MyField                  :            1234
```

I was expecting, however:

```
MyField                  :        1,234.00
```

The expected result is correcly returned if I add evaluation brackets around the 1234:

```
Write-Output (Get-FormattedNameValuePair -name MyField -value (1234))
```

The formatting also works without the evaluation brackets if called directly instead of wrapped within the 'Get-FormattedNameValuePair' function.

```
[string] $name = "MyField"
[object] $value = 1234
Write-Output  "$("{0,-24}" -f $name) : $("{0,15:N2}" -f $value)"
```

Can anyone explain the behavior above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't reproduce this on V3

```
Function Get-FormattedNameValuePair([string] $name, [object] $value)
{
    return "$("{0,-24}" -f $name) : $("{0,15:N2}" -f $value)"
}

Write-Output (Get-FormattedNameValuePair -name MyField -value 1234)

MyField                  :        1,234.00
```

But I can repro this on V2. If you change the `[object]` cast to `[int]` it starts working as you expect.  There's something about putting this in an object that is causing the problem.  This error can be shown a bit more succinctly like so:

```
function foo([object]$o) { "{0,15:N2}" -f $o }
foo 1234
       1234
```

In V2 there are a number of known issues related to the wrapping of .NET types in a PowerShell extended type system type known as PSObject.  This looks to be related to that issue. And indeed it is related.  Check this out:

```
function foo([object]$o) { "{0,15:N2}" -f $o.psobject.baseobject }
foo 1234
   1,234.00
```

If you unwrap the object to get back to the original, you get the expected output. Chalk this up to a V2 bug that is fortunately fixed in V3.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I'm on PS version 2.0 as shown by $Host.Version. I get the result "MyField : 1234", while I was expecting "MyField : 1,234.00". What result do you get?

Comment: @MikeRosenblum I was able to repro this on V2 as well. Updated my answer to explain what's going on.

Comment: Superb answer Keith, thanks for putting in the time to check this out so thoroughly.